# How to subset a SQL table using previous records condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I query the table that ignores rows having consecutive 0 values in the last 4 weeks / records? This for example (Note that there can be other IDs too that might have records on the previous weeks):

Initial Table:

| WEEK | ID | SALES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | 1 | 0 |
| 202002 | 1 | 0 |
| 202003 | 1 | 0 |
| 202004 | 1 | 0 |
| 202005 | 1 | 3 |
| 202006 | 1 | 0 |
| 202007 | 1 | 0 |
| 202008 | 1 | 5 |

Output Table:

| WEEK | ID | SALES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202005 | 1 | 3 |
| 202006 | 1 | 0 |
| 202007 | 1 | 0 |
| 202008 | 1 | 5 |

I use 2 tables here to pull the data. So far I've tried doing a 2 step code:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_SALES AS
SELECT 
B.WEEK_NBR,
A.ID
B.SALES
FROM 
PRODUCT_TABLE A,
SALES_TABLE B
WHERE 
A.ID= B.ID(+);
```

Then I try to get the minimum week where Sales = 0 but now I'm stuck here since after I get the min weeks for every product ID. I'm not sure what to do next or how it can be used to subset the main table.

```
SELECT 
(WEEK_NBR) MIN_WEEK_SALES,
ID,
SALES
FROM 
PRODUCT_SALES 
WHERE SALES = 0;
```

I was wondering if there's another way I can code this?

Comment: I'm using Snowflake. I tagged oracle because I use Oracle SQL syntax sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

use lag() window function

```
with cte as (select
WEEK,SALES,
lag(SALES,1)over(order by w) as sales1,
lag(SALES,2)over(order by w) as sales2,
lag(SALES,3)over(order by w) as sales3,ID from t
) select WEEK,SALES,ID from cte where 
(coalesce(SALES,0)+coalesce(sales1,0)+coalesce(sales2,0)+coalesce(sales3,0) )<>0
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6535589170a5767157bb7a7f51993b19)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you help me understand why we lag it 3 times separately? If I add another sales 4 lag there then it takes the last 5 records with nulls correct?